# How to use dynamic EF Query with OR values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How to use dynamic EF Query with OR values. I want to get out all people in `PeopleGroups` 3 or 4 this time, but next time perhaps `PeopleGroups` 5 or 8

This work, hardcoded. `PeopleGroups` is not primary `Id`

```
var Peoples = db.People.Where(_ => (_.PeopleGroups == 3 || _.PeopleGroups == 4));
```

But how to get it dynamic? I thought of `.Contains()` but its only work with primary `Id` I think

```
var searchPeopleGroups = new List<int> { 3, 4 };  
var Peoples = db.People.Where(_ => searchPeopleGroups.Contains(_.PeopleGroups));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Contains()` method will work, and should generate an IN clause in the resulting SQL query.

If you want a truly dynamic solution, that generates an OR statement in the resulting SQL query, I suggest using the [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) framework, along with the included `PredicateBuilder` class.

If you include LinqKit, your query can become something similar to:

```
Expression<Func<People, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<People>();

foreach (var g in searchPeopleGroups)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.PeopleGroups == g);
}

var Peoples = db.People.AsExpandable().Where(predicate.Expand());
```

Comment: Great I got it to work!

I tried '.Contains' again but couldnt get it to work